# Separate Buttons for jQuery toggle event with cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, width, toggle

I have made a jQuery toggle, where user can select the width of theme to be fluid or fixed with a toggle button.
The thing is working fine, but i want to add separate toggle buttons one for fixed width on click and another for fluid width on click.

I tried, but i was not successful.

Here is the code i have used

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
var setWidth = $.cookie("width");
if (typeof setWidth !== "undefined" && setWidth == "85%") {
    $('#container,.wrp').width(setWidth); // 85% width set using cookie
} else if (typeof setWidth !== "undefined" && setWidth == "960px") {
    $('#container,.wrp').width(setWidth); // 960px,1000px(for wrp) width set using cookie
}
$('#toggle-button').click(function () {
    var toggleWidth = $("#container").width() == 960 ? "85%" : "960px";

    $('#container, .wrp').animate({
        width: toggleWidth
    });
    $.cookie('width', toggleWidth);
});
});
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/envira/kTrLL/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another on click function with a new button.

```
$('#toggle-button-resp').click(function () {
    var toggleWidth = "85%";

    $('#container, .wrp').animate({
        width: toggleWidth
    });
    $.cookie('width', toggleWidth);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gasp10/kTrLL/1/)

Comment: Hello,Thanks a lot for the help. Yeah, i tried this and it works, but i meant is there any way possibility that the toggle switches can be like : if fixed is clicked fixed would be hidden and in the same block, fluid button is shown. Like the buttons to overlap eachother. I hope you got what i say. Thank you

Comment: I meant here is an example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/envira/NS9Z8/ @Emanuele Parisio Thank you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gasp10/NS9Z8/3/ toggle the .hidden class, don't use inline style if you can